# Is the function $f(x,y,z)=\sqrt{x^2 +y^2} +z^2$ smooth?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by

> $$f(x,y,z)=\sqrt{x^2 +y^2} +z^2 .$$

Is this function smooth? My head is telling me there should be a problem when $x=y=0$, but I'm not sure. Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Along the line $(x,y,z)=(t,0,0)$ the function looks like $|t|$, not smooth.

Answer (score 4):

Your intuition is correct: Applying the definition gives that, e.g., the partial derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ does not even exist at $(0, 0, 0)$, and hence $f$ is not even differentiable once there, let alone smooth.